# Newton's color Disk

Tags: optics, visible-light, spectroscopy, biophysics

How does Newton's color disk work?

Newton's disk - Take a circular white color disk, make 7 equal intersections and paint section with respective VIBGYOR colors, now when you spin the disk in certain speed, it appears white.

Comment: Could you five some more information on what that is?

Comment: Newton's disk - we take a circular white color disk make 7 equal intersections and Paint section with respective VIBGYOR colors,Now when you spin the disk in certain speed,It appears white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perception of a picture or a color stays in the human brain for a fraction of a second. Newton's color disk is a mechanical device that rotates an array of colors arranged as petals or gradients around an axis and when the disc rotates fast enough the perception of the color changes to white. This is because white light is nothing but the mixture of light of all wavelengths in the visible range.

Sir Isaac Newton used this device to prove the above assertion that white color is the mixture of all colors.

Comment: I doubt this is right.  If the perception of a color stays in your brain for a fraction of second, then the mixing of colors is not physical mixing, but neurological.  How does your brain know to mix colors the same way nature does?

Comment: The whiteness is a perception. It is of course a neurological phenomenon. The superposition of all colors create an impression of whiteness, just like light of specific wavelength create an impression of redness. What's the problem?

Comment: According to your answer, the colors are perceived separately by the senses, but mixed by the brain.  So at no point is there an actual superposition of colors.  No red light is ever falling on top of any blue light, for example.  The only mixing, as it's described is in the brain.  You can't superpose neurological phenomenon and then simply assert you'll get the same result as superposing physical ones.

Comment: @sb1 small matter, but I thought it was the photoreceptor cells on the retina that retain the sensation of color, not really the brain itself. (Then again I'm not a biologist)

Comment: I am not an expert on how brain works. What I do know is brain can mix these colors to create an impression of white light and Newton used this experiment as a demonstration of the fact that white light is composed of different colors.

Comment: @sb1 Unfortunately, the one simply is not a demonstration of the other.

Comment: @David: I am not a biologist either :). But, I think any perception is ultimately an action of brain. Isn't it?

Comment: @Mark, white light is only mixed in the brain even when it's not on a rotating color disk. There are three different types of cone cells in our eyes which respond to three different wavelength ranges; which color we perceive depends on the relative signals coming from the different types of cells. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell

Comment: There is a lot of "data preprocessing" in the retina. Whether this includes the color mixing I don't know. BTW such disks do not really produce "white", the best they do is a light grey. Problem is, that there are no real perfect paints to represent the primary  colors.

Comment: if the receptors in the eye have some relaxation time similar to a CCD then it doesnt matter if the colours don't arrive simultaneously as long they arrive within some finite dt, then the signals can be either mixed in the eye sending white to the brain or the signals will overlap when arriving at the brain and again the result is white (or grey!).  But I also am not a biologist.

Comment: @Georg: not only problem of "perfect paints". If the disk is painted 3 primary colors (RGB), each kind of photoreceptor registers given primary color 1/3 the time, lack of said color 2/3 the time. Meaning the brightness of the "white" is reduced by 2/3 vs brightness of the 3 paints just mixed together. Use CMY instead for only 1/3 reduction of brightness (each primary color is present on 2 out of 3 fields.)

Comment: @SF, This is not so easy, SF. Whether You "see" light grey (instead of white) , or rose instead of deep red, is a question of illumination around that color field.

Comment: There's an even more interesting optical illusion that is sort of "dual" to Newton's disk. If you take a disk with a black and white pattern on it, and rotate it, it appears to have color (for certain combinations of rotation speed and spacing between black and white regions). I don't know what this one is called, unfortunately. I think that the explanation is that the white excites all three color receptors in the eye, but the three receptors have different decay times, so that a time-varying black-and-white signal will end up exciting some receptors more than others, in a time-average sense.

Comment: @Ted It's called "I actually got sick just thinking about a black and white spining disk. :-("